# How to Decompose XML to Relational DB with the help of tool available by Microsoft?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, sql-server-2008

My organisation is using [Adlib software](http://www.adlibsoft.com/) to store the information about all the resources we have.
My project is to  make those data available to visitors by means of a website which gives visitors an interface to make search on those resources.

The API's given by Adlib vendor gives me XML [Click this to see an example of xml those API returns](http://test2.adlibsoft.com/api/wwwopac.ashx?database=collect.inf&search=all&xmltype=grouped). My project needs to decompose the XML to MS SQL Relational Database.

The problem is according to me the XML that I get is Unstructured and I am not able to decide what should I use to decompose like `Open XML`, `select for XML`, `Xquery` or anything else (that I am not aware of!).
I just want to maintain the local database so that the Website can then use it as a read-only purpose only and visitors can search the resources.

```
    <adlibXML>
<recordList>
<record priref="1" selected="False">
<Acquisition_source>
<acquisition.source>Parker, Mrs</acquisition.source>
<acquisition.source.lref>2</acquisition.source.lref>
<acquisition.source.type/>
</Acquisition_source>
<Alternative_number>
<alternative_number>1964.517</alternative_number>
<alternative_number.type>Collection number</alternative_number.type>
</Alternative_number>
<collection>TEXTILES</collection>
<collection.lref>1</collection.lref>
<Condition>
<condition.date>1999-01</condition.date>
<condition.notes>
<value lang="">Bottom right corner, worn and now frayed.</value>
</condition.notes>
</Condition>
<current_location>Room 20 - Cube</current_location>
<current_location.lref>3500</current_location.lref>
<current_location.type/>
<Description>
<description>
The top is in white cotton with pieced and appliqué patchwork in dress prints; the back is in white cotton. Cotton wool padding. Patchwork forms a square in white border; centre and corners of square are panels of appliqué (hearts, birds, clover leafs etc). Sides of square are pieced pieces; quilting follows patchwork with border quilted in large diamonds, and each containing a form four-hearts spray. Very neatly and prettily worked. Worked by donor's grandmother, Mrs Rebecca Temperley, possibly for her wedding in 1860. Prov: Mrs. Parker.
</description>
</Description>
<Dimension>
<dimension.notes/>
<dimension.part/>
<dimension.precision/>
<dimension.type>Length</dimension.type>
<dimension.type.lref>15</dimension.type.lref>
<dimension.unit>cm</dimension.unit>
<dimension.unit.lref>16</dimension.unit.lref>
<dimension.value>270</dimension.value>
</Dimension>
<Dimension>
<dimension.notes/>
<dimension.part/>
<dimension.precision/>
<dimension.type>Width</dimension.type>
<dimension.type.lref>14</dimension.type.lref>
<dimension.unit>cm</dimension.unit>
<dimension.unit.lref>16</dimension.unit.lref>
<dimension.value>270</dimension.value>
</Dimension>
<documentation.free_text>Patchwork Quilts / Colby, Averil p. 59</documentation.free_text>
<documentation.free_text>Quilts / Baird, Ljiljana p. 35</documentation.free_text>
<documentation.free_text>Patchwork Quilt Tsushin p. 21</documentation.free_text>
<documentation.free_text>North Country Quilting</documentation.free_text>
<documentation.free_text>
North Country Quilts: Legend and Living Tradition / Osler, Dorothy p. 23
</documentation.free_text>
<Edit>
<edit.date>2012-04-12</edit.date>
<edit.name>bridget.westmacott</edit.name>
<edit.source>collect>intern</edit.source>
<edit.time>09:49:34</edit.time>
</Edit>
<Edit>
<edit.date>2012-04-12</edit.date>
<edit.name>bridget.westmacott</edit.name>
<edit.source>collect>intern</edit.source>
<edit.time>09:49:06</edit.time>
</Edit>
<Edit>
<edit.date>2012-04-10</edit.date>
<edit.name>bridget.westmacott</edit.name>
<edit.source>collect>intern</edit.source>
<edit.time>09:34:24</edit.time>
</Edit>
<Edit>
<edit.date>2012-02-16</edit.date>
<edit.name>darren.stirk</edit.name>
<edit.source>collect>intern</edit.source>
<edit.time>14:28:23</edit.time>
</Edit>
<Edit>
<edit.date>2012-02-16</edit.date>
<edit.name>siddharth.pandey</edit.name>
<edit.source>collect>intern</edit.source>
<edit.time>13:35:34</edit.time>
</Edit>
<Edit>
<edit.date>2012-02-16</edit.date>
<edit.name>siddharth.pandey</edit.name>
<edit.source>collect>intern</edit.source>
<edit.time>13:28:51</edit.time>
</Edit>
<Edit>
<edit.date>2011-01-07</edit.date>
<edit.name>bridget.westmacott</edit.name>
<edit.source>collect>intern</edit.source>
<edit.time>10:02:11</edit.time>
</Edit>
<Edit>
<edit.date>2011-01-07</edit.date>
<edit.name>bridget.westmacott</edit.name>
<edit.source>collect>intern</edit.source>
<edit.time>10:01:49</edit.time>
</Edit>
<Edit>
<edit.date>2011-01-07</edit.date>
<edit.name>bridget.westmacott</edit.name>
<edit.source>collect>intern</edit.source>
<edit.time>09:54:17</edit.time>
</Edit>
<Edit>
<edit.date>2011-01-07</edit.date>
<edit.name>bridget.westmacott</edit.name>
<edit.source>collect>intern</edit.source>
<edit.time>09:48:09</edit.time>
</Edit>
<Edit>
<edit.date>2007-04-17</edit.date>
<edit.name>bridget.westmacott</edit.name>
<edit.source>collect>intern</edit.source>
<edit.time>10:37:52</edit.time>
</Edit>
<Exhibition>
<exhibition>North Country Quilting</exhibition>
<exhibition.catalogue_number/>
<exhibition.date.end>1963-10-01</exhibition.date.end>
<exhibition.date.start>1963-07-12</exhibition.date.start>
<exhibition.lref>1</exhibition.lref>
<exhibition.notes>
Wedding quilt, pieced and appliquéd in plain and printed cottons. Quilted in a bordered design. Made by Rebecca Temperley of Allendale, Northumberland, c. 1860 Q.18 (No. 4 in Booklet)
</exhibition.notes>
<exhibition.organiser/>
<exhibition.reference_number/>
<exhibition.venue/>
<exhibition.venue.place/>
</Exhibition>
<Exhibition>
<exhibition>Shipley Art Gallery</exhibition>
<exhibition.catalogue_number/>
<exhibition.date.end>1983-04-01</exhibition.date.end>
<exhibition.date.start>1983-03-01</exhibition.date.start>
<exhibition.lref>2</exhibition.lref>
<exhibition.notes/>
<exhibition.organiser/>
<exhibition.reference_number/>
<exhibition.venue>Shipley Art Gallery</exhibition.venue>
<exhibition.venue.place/>
</Exhibition>
<Exhibition>
<exhibition>Northern Quilts and Covers</exhibition>
<exhibition.catalogue_number/>
<exhibition.date.end>1990-05-13</exhibition.date.end>
<exhibition.date.start>1990-03-10</exhibition.date.start>
<exhibition.lref>3</exhibition.lref>
<exhibition.notes/>
<exhibition.organiser/>
<exhibition.reference_number/>
<exhibition.venue/>
<exhibition.venue.place/>
</Exhibition>
<Exhibition>
<exhibition>Bowes Museum</exhibition>
<exhibition.catalogue_number/>
<exhibition.date.end>1992-12-01</exhibition.date.end>
<exhibition.date.start>1991-05-01</exhibition.date.start>
<exhibition.lref>4</exhibition.lref>
<exhibition.notes>
Pieced and applied Quilt by Rebecca Temperley, Allendale, Northumberland, 1860 Plain and printed cottons, pieced and applied in a bordered design, quilted design echoes the applied design. The border has a "lined twist" quatrefoil hearts and leaf patterns. Underside of white cotton, hand-stitched edge. Gift of Mrs. Parker Q.18.1964.517 This fine quilt is said to have been made by Rebecca Temperley for her wedding in 1860. The applique hearts and quatre foils, to represent the four-leafed clover, are motifs often associated with marriage quilts.
</exhibition.notes>
<exhibition.organiser/>
<exhibition.reference_number/>
<exhibition.venue/>
<exhibition.venue.place/>
</Exhibition>
<Exhibition>
<exhibition>North Country Quilts: Legend & Living Tradition</exhibition>
<exhibition.catalogue_number/>
<exhibition.date.end>2001-03-07</exhibition.date.end>
<exhibition.date.start>2000-08-05</exhibition.date.start>
<exhibition.lref>5</exhibition.lref>
<exhibition.notes>
Pieced and Appliqued quilt Made by Rebecca Temperley, probably in Allendale c.1860 (possibly for Rebecca's wedding) Printed and white cottons, reverse white cotton Bordered quilting design includes Clamshell, Wave, Cable Twist, and Geometric border with Roses. 274 x 274 cm (108 x 108 inches)
</exhibition.notes>
<exhibition.organiser/>
<exhibition.reference_number/>
<exhibition.venue>The Bowes Museum</exhibition.venue>
<exhibition.venue.place/>
</Exhibition>
<input.date>2000-12-05</input.date>
<input.name>Administrator</input.name>
<input.source>collect>intern</input.source>
<input.time>12:17:18</input.time>
<Label>
<label.text>
Maker Mrs. Rebecca Temperley Allendale, c.1860 (possibly for her wedding) Printed and white cotton, reverse white cotton. A bordered design includes Clamshell, Cable Twist, and Geometric border with Roses. Size: 274 x 274 cm.
</label.text>
<label.type>
<value lang="neutral">WEBTEXT</value>
<value lang="0">website text</value>
<value lang="1">website-tekst</value>
<value lang="2">texte site web</value>
<value lang="3">Website-Text</value>
<value lang="6">κείμενο διαδκτυακού τόπου</value>
</label.type>
</Label>
<Label>
<label.text>abcdefg</label.text>
<label.type>
<value lang="neutral">WEBTEXT</value>
<value lang="0">website text</value>
<value lang="1">website-tekst</value>
<value lang="2">texte site web</value>
<value lang="3">Website-Text</value>
<value lang="6">κείμενο διαδκτυακού τόπου</value>
</label.type>
</Label>
<Label>
<label.text>def</label.text>
<label.type>
<value lang="neutral">EDUCATIONALTEXT</value>
<value lang="0">educational text</value>
<value lang="1">educatieve tekst</value>
<value lang="2">texte éducatif</value>
<value lang="3">Museumspädagogischer Text</value>
<value lang="6">εκπαιδευτικό κείμενο</value>
</label.type>
</Label>
<location.default>Room 20 - Cube</location.default>
<location.default.lref>3500</location.default.lref>
<location.default.type/>
<Material>
<material>Cotton</material>
<material.lref>9</material.lref>
<material.notes/>
<material.part/>
</Material>
<notes>
Rebecca Temperley (active 1860). English (Allendale, Northumberland). Quilt, c.1860 Printed and white cottons, reverse white cotton. A bordered design includes Clamshell, Cable Twist, and Geometric border with Roses. Presented by Mrs Parker 1964.
</notes>
<object_category>Bedcovers or Coverlets</object_category>
<object_category.lref>426</object_category.lref>
<Object_name>
<object_name>
<value lang="">Quilt</value>
</object_name>
<object_name.authority/>
<object_name.authority.lref/>
<object_name.lref>17</object_name.lref>
<object_name.notes/>
<object_name.type>Pieced and Appliqued</object_name.type>
<object_name.type.lref>416</object_name.type.lref>
</Object_name>
<object_number>QUILT.18</object_number>
<priref>1</priref>
<Production>
<creator>
<value lang="">Temperley, Mrs Rebecca</value>
</creator>
<creator.date_of_birth/>
<creator.date_of_death/>
<creator.history/>
<creator.lref>1</creator.lref>
<creator.qualifier/>
<creator.role/>
<creator.role.lref/>
<production.notes/>
<production.place>Allendale</production.place>
<production.place.lref>5</production.place.lref>
</Production>
<production.period>19th century</production.period>
<production.period>Victorian</production.period>
<production.period.lref>13</production.period.lref>
<production.period.lref>12</production.period.lref>
<Production_date>
<production.date.end>1870</production.date.end>
<production.date.end.prec>circa</production.date.end.prec>
<production.date.start>1850</production.date.start>
<production.date.start.prec>circa</production.date.start.prec>
</Production_date>
<record_access.owner>null</record_access.owner>
<record_type>
<value lang="neutral">OBJECT</value>
<value lang="0">single object</value>
<value lang="2">objet individuel</value>
<value lang="3">Einzelnes Objekt</value>
</record_type>
<Reproduction>
<reproduction.creator/>
<reproduction.date/>
<reproduction.format/>
<reproduction.notes/>
<reproduction.reference>../../collections database/images/qlt-18.jpg</reproduction.reference>
<reproduction.reference.lref>1</reproduction.reference.lref>
<reproduction.type/>
<reproduction.web_exclusion/>
</Reproduction>
<Reproduction>
<reproduction.creator/>
<reproduction.date/>
<reproduction.format/>
<reproduction.notes/>
<reproduction.reference>
../../collections database/images/qlt-18-detail.jpg
</reproduction.reference>
<reproduction.reference.lref>2</reproduction.reference.lref>
<reproduction.type/>
<reproduction.web_exclusion/>
</Reproduction>
<Reproduction>
<reproduction.creator/>
<reproduction.date/>
<reproduction.format/>
<reproduction.notes/>
<reproduction.reference>
../../collections database/images/qlt-18-detail-b.jpg
</reproduction.reference>
<reproduction.reference.lref>3</reproduction.reference.lref>
<reproduction.type/>
<reproduction.web_exclusion/>
</Reproduction>
<Reproduction>
<reproduction.creator/>
<reproduction.date/>
<reproduction.format/>
<reproduction.notes/>
<reproduction.reference>
../../collections database/images/qlt-18-detail-c.jpg
</reproduction.reference>
<reproduction.reference.lref>4</reproduction.reference.lref>
<reproduction.type/>
<reproduction.web_exclusion/>
</Reproduction>
<Technique>
<technique>Pieced</technique>
<technique.lref>11</technique.lref>
<technique.notes/>
<technique.part/>
</Technique>
<Technique>
<technique>Applique</technique>
<technique.lref>7</technique.lref>
<technique.notes/>
<technique.part/>
</Technique>
<Technique>
<technique>Handsewn</technique>
<technique.lref>10</technique.lref>
<technique.notes/>
<technique.part/>
</Technique>
<Technique>
<technique>Patchwork</technique>
<technique.lref>6</technique.lref>
<technique.notes/>
<technique.part/>
</Technique>
<Title>
<title>
<value lang="">Patchwork Quilt</value>
</title>
</Title>
</record>
</recordList>
<diagnostic>
<hits>38049</hits>
<xmltype>Grouped</xmltype>
<first_item>1</first_item>
<search>All</search>
<sort/>
<limit>1</limit>
<hits_on_display>1</hits_on_display>
<response_time unit="mS" culture="en-GB">639.0639</response_time>
<xml_creation_time unit="mS" culture="en-GB">13.0013</xml_creation_time>
<link_resolve_time unit="mS" culture="en-GB">5.0005</link_resolve_time>
<dbname>collect</dbname>
<dsname>intern</dsname>
<cgistring>
<param name="database">ChoiceCollect</param>
</cgistring>
</diagnostic>
</adlibXML>
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with `openxml`

Comment: I have never used Openxml. So, I don't have any clue!

Comment: My thesis on the subject (pdf):

http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CFUQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fciteseerx.ist.psu.edu%2Fviewdoc%2Fdownload%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.85.5993%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&ei=YwW2T4XCG4qriQLtmsWgBw&usg=AFQjCNHPBq469XSJPYgnXp0Ng6Qo18gHUA&sig2=kc6KXM3VJ1jkRH3BP2HbDA

Answer (score 0):

You can you MS SQL Servers Full Text feature to accomplish this see [Use Full-Text Search with XML Columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522491.aspx)

Comment: How can I use this to migrate data from those returned XML to MS SQL DB? We have about 50K objects in that Adlib Software. So once the local DB is defined with the information of 50K objects, my code then can search faster.

Comment: How do you get the data? Is it static or do you have a service or something that takes in XML content for insertion?

Comment: You can get started with the [Full-Text Search Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142547(v=sql.105).aspx) ? I did a quick search on a tutorial of how to insert XML and found [this](http://www.a2zdotnet.com/view.aspx?id=70#.T7IpzWt5mK0). You can probably find better ones though.

Comment: I have a web service through which I can get data for respective datasets namely ChoiceCollect, ChoiceArchive,ChoiceBooks, ChoiceFullCatalogue by passing this at the place of collect.inf in above test URL.

Comment: In that case, try to get the XML content from a test request. Once you can get that XML, see if you can try getting an INSERT statement working with that test XML into your database. Once you get XML into the DB then, happy querying !

Comment: Full-Text Search directly searches for the values that we pass in contain() method and we can filter it by specifying the tags and attributes. So, are you telling me to fetch particular values that I want and store those values in the local database? And then the search operation performed by visitor will be processed using our local datbase. I am understanding the scenario like this!

Comment: Yes sir, since all the XML you are getting is unstructured.

Comment: Also, I am not able to decide the structure of the DB as the xml that I get has some elements that appear n no. of times. Please see the content of my question above. I have updated it.

Comment: The most interesting column for you will be a single column of type XML. Unless, of course, you find a way to structure your data then you can start querying the data in a traditional RDBMS fashion. I am not sure what your other requirements are. Is each XML object associated with a person for example? Then you can store that data in another column with the XML column.

Comment: The xml that you can see above is of one artifact that belongs to one category of collections dataset i.e. the hierarchy goes like this Collections > Category > Artifact. I can manually create tables for Collections, Category as I know the exact values. But for Artifact, I need to do it by the method we have just discussed above.

Comment: I see, so it's semi-structured. Creating columns for the parsed structured part of the XML object seems like a good idea. Just make sure you need that part of the data.

Comment: I am not clear with **Creating columns for the parsed structured part of the XML object.**

Comment: Every XML object is associated with a category right? Create a category column in your table. Once you parse the category from the object, put it into the category column of your table.

Comment: ok I got you. Now, I will play with Full-Text Search with sample XML and will try to fetch values on the basis of elements and attributes. If it works, then I will work on the architecture of my DB. Hope this process will run without any problems for 50,000 objects!